# Problems with python class inheritance

Tags: python, class, inheritance, python-2.x

I'm playing around with python class inheritance, but I can't seem to get the child class working.

The error message that I'm getting here is:

```
must be a type not classobj
```

Here is the code:

```
class User():
    """Creates a user class and stores info"""
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age, nickname):
        self.name = first_name
        self.surname = last_name
        self.age = age
        self.nickname = nickname
        self.login_attempts = 0

    def describe_user(self):
        print("The users name is " + self.name.title() + " " + self.surname.title() + "!")
        print("He is " + str(self.age) + " year's old!")
        print("He uses the name " + self.nickname.title() + "!")

    def greet_user(self):
        print("Hello " + self.nickname.title() + "!")

    def increment_login_attempts(self):
        self.login_attempts += 1

    def reset_login_attempts(self):
        self.login_attempts = 0

class Admin(User):
    """This is just a specific user"""
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age, nickname):
        """Initialize the atributes of a parent class"""
        super(Admin, self).__init__(first_name, last_name, age, nickname)

jack = Admin('Jack', 'Sparrow', 35, 'captain js')
jack.describe_user()
```

I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `User` class must inherit from `object` if you are going to call `super()` on it later.

```
class User(object):

...
```

Python2 distinguishes between old-style classes that did not inherit from `object` and new style classes that do.  It's best to use new style classes in modern code, and never good to mix them in an inheritance hierarchy.